# Powerpivot DAX sum based on row value

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I am trying to create a running total based on 4 criteria but can't seem to get it to work - sorry very new to both powerpivot and DAX.

I have a Query that has a total of 17 columns - 13 actual data and 4 calculated.

I want to get a cumulative total based on 4 criteria. 
I haven't even been able to get 1 criteria working so far:

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Tonnes),
    Filter(Query,[Deliveryid]=[Deliveryid])
    )
```

Basically want to sum all the tonnes for each deliveryid - this is simple in a pivot, but i want to eventually do this for all dates before the date value in the row and for each commodity and delivery address etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I highly recommend this site: http://www.daxpatterns.com It makes it look easy but let me assure it definitely isn't, but it's definitely worth learning.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Looks good. Still very new to DAX so any resource is a good one!

Comment: Sorry I can't answer your question - still learning myself. But one thing I learnt the hard way: unlike a SQL expression, if you have joined columns, it makes a big difference which column (the column in the fact or the column in your dimension) that you use in your expression.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific requirement to sum all the tonnes for each Deliveryid, you're close. Try this: `=CALCULATE(SUMX(Table1,[Tonnes]),FILTER(Table1,[Deliveryid]=EARLIER([Deliveryid])))`. It will sum the Tonnes for each Deliveryid.

Regarding your follow-on desire to sum all the tonnes for each Deliveryid for the dates preceding the current date, try this: `=CALCULATE(SUMX(Table1,[Tonnes]),FILTER(FILTER(Table1,[Deliveryid]=EARLIER([Deliveryid])),[Date]<EARLIER([Date])))`.

The table below might help show what these do (I used very long column titles to hopefully make this more understandable):

TotalTonnesForDeliveryid (made with the first code item above) simply totals tonnes by Deliveryid. In the table below, you see the TotalTonnesForDeliveryid for Deliveryid 1 is 91 tonnes ... 38 (from 1/1/2017) + 23 (from 1/3/2017) + 30 (from 1/6/2017).

TotalTonnesForDeliveryBeforeCurrentDate (made with the second code item above) totals tonnes by Deliveryid *only for the dates preceding the current date*. The reason TotalTonnesForDeliveryBeforeCurrentDate shows blanks for first occurences of Deliveryid is because there was no prior delivery. If more than one delivery has been made for a particular Deliveryid, each following occurence of the Deliveryid shows an accumulation of the previous dates' tonnes. So for Deliveryid 1: the initial delivery date (1/1/2017) shows blank TotalTonnesForDeliveryidBeforeCurrentDate (because there was no previous delivery); the second delivery date (1/3/2017) shows 38 tonnes (which is what was delivered on 1/1/2017); and the third delivery date (1/6/2017) shows 61 tonnes (which is the 38 from the first delivery + the 23 from the second delivery).

[image]

Comment: You sir are a legend. Apologies for the super late rely, I didn't actually see this again.

I am still learning DAX and the company is going down the PowerBI/PowerPivot route and I would like to be the super user. Which includes DAX and SQL. Any resources would be super useful!